# Are there any geological periods found on top of each other that have dinosaurs of that period with in them?

Tags: evolution, geology, paleontology, fossil-record

In diagrams, It is common to depict geological periods to be directly on top of each other with fossils of that period within them. When looking for evidence of this, I have only found examples of trilobites and shells. However it is common to see this sort of ordering depicted with dinosaurs in them http://www.globalchange.umich.edu/globalchange1/current/lectures/complex_life/fossil_record.html

In high school my teacher said that at the grand canyon we find no fossils at the bottom, further up we find shells, above that we find jellyfish, then fish, then reptiles, then mammals. After doing research I found out that this was not the case. Now I suspect that diagrams that depict this ordering of the fossil record with dinosaurs maybe deception or at least a representation of the fossil record that can be easily misinterpreted by laymen.

So are there any examples of this sort of ordering?

Note: I know the wording of the question is quite terrible. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Would it be useful to insert the following text to the question? `It's easy to find "notable claims" for this e.g. by searching Google for 'fossil layers' ... for example, [Fossils help geologists establish the ages of layers of rock](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/media/108884/Fossils-help-geologists-establish-the-ages-of-layers-of-rock)`

Comment: Not exactly, as it does not depict dinosaurs of different periods (I know I didn't specify I wanted this, but that was what I had in mind as that is the most common example I see). Nonetheless the shell diagram will do and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Where's the notable claim that this isn't the case?

Comment: I am finding the question title confusing. Have I got this right? You want to know whether the typical public understanding of palaeontology is correct - i.e. that there are strata of rocks underground that were laid in successive geologic periods, that more recent layers appear higher**, and that each layer only includes fossils of lifeforms that were present in the corresponding geologic period.

Comment: ** Note to geologists: Yes, inverted strata. I know. I am just trying to clarify the question, not answer it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: If the OP is asking in good faith, we don't require that. See [this meta-question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c).

Comment: @Oddthinking I think the important part of the question is "directly on top". So, a layer of rock with fossils, and a different layer of rock with different fossils elsewhere (e.g. miles away) wouldn't count. Are there examples of layers with different fossils "directly on top" of each other? Apparently the OP's teacher claimed that the Grand Canyon was thus, and the OP has learned that it isn't.

Comment: I've voted to close it while we get some clarification.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think we are saying the same thing from very different directions--I was asking what claim he was talking about, you're voting to close as not clear.

Comment: @Loren: Ah, okay. (For the record, I started by merely asking for a clarification, but as I saw it was getting more confused, I voted to close - at this point, someone attempting to answer will likely make it worse, not better.)

Comment: @Oddthinking Okay I did a little research to find grand canyon fossils in order but only with shells and trilomtes. I have three questions now (questons lead to more questions after all) I will ask two in ths comment as I do not think it will require a long answer and I will change my question to ask the third question I have. Queston 1 & 2: At the grand canyon how far apart are the fossils in each layer? Miles? directly on top? or both? and just how many fossil do we find at the grand canyon?

Comment: @Oddthinking - IMHO, for topics that have their own SE (e.g. geology/paleontology having Earth Sciences SE), questions dealing with the basic fundamentals of that discipline are better off on the on-topic SE than here.

Comment: @DVK I know I am new and everything so my opinion is almost worthless, but I thought I would give my 2 cents (or 1 cent if you like). Since it is a widely believed claim doesn't that mean it can go on Skeptic SE? Of course this sort of question can also go on earth science SE but not many people use it and I think that this is a question the Skeptic SE community might be curious of the answer to.

Comment: @RayKay - the chances of a great answer from a subject matter professional are higher on a specialist site

Comment: @DVK The same could be said about any science or history question on Skeptic SE.

Comment: @RayKay - Not all science questions have their own SEs. But yes, general history questions are better off on History.SE long term.

Comment: @DVKi am not talking about general history questions, I am talking about historical claims that people are skeptical of. Also I see questions related to evolutionary claims on this site quite often and people answer them (assuming it is asked with good intent) I think you just want an excuse not to answer it as the answer is not in your favor. Seeing that you have 15,000 reputation points it suggest you understand that the truth is all that matters, even if the evidence goes against it (or lack of evidence in this case). Its not like anyone is going to become a creationist over it anyway.

Comment: [Also on Earth Science.](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4400/are-there-any-geological-periods-found-on-top-of-each-other-that-have-dinosaurs)